# Setting multiple global variables within functions

Tags: powershell, variables, scope

I have multiple global variables in my script that I use within a function.

```
$global:Row_array = @();
$global:Column_Array = @();
$global:Sorted_Array = @();
$global:totalrows = 0;
$global:array=@();
$global:m_file;

# Button Click Event Handler...
$Run_It.add_Click({
    for($i=0; $i -lt 6; $i++){
        $global:Row_array += $i
    }
    ...
    ...
 })
```

Now do I need to put the `$global:` qualifier in front of every global variable inside this event handler?

Or can I do something like this:

```
$Run_It.add_Click({
    for($i=0; $i -lt 6; $i++){
        Row_array += $i
    }
    ...
    ...
    # At the very end...
    $global:Row_array = $Row_array;
    $global:Column_Array = $Column_Array;
    $global:Sorted_Array = $Sorted_Array;
    ...
})
```

I can do a global replace in the editor of all the variables and put `$global:` in front but wanted to know if there is a more elegant way. The `ref` keyword is problematic? Also, whether functions using global variables is a good idea or not is a separate discussion… I am using it for a temporary project.

Comment: Yes, you can do as your second example suggests.

Comment: Thank you Mathias... Just tried it. It works !...

Comment: @Sorizon: Put the second one as an answer